# Why target for dynamic dispatch is not determined at compile time?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, superclass, method-dispatch

I am now reading a Java book and stuck for quite a while now thinking about how Dynamic Method Dispatch works. I understand that it's a powerful and valuable feature but I don't understand its main principle. For example, I have a class B which inherits from class A and overrides some of A's methods. So, when I write a program, I may use these expressions

```
A a = new B();
a.someOverridenMethod();
```

I know that in this situation the version B of method will be called, not A. But the part that I don't understand is, why can't the compiler determine which version (superclass or some subclass) of the method to call? I mean, it's explicitly stated that the variable `a` will hold a reference to object of type B. So why is it only possible to determine this at runtime even though it's explicitly stated in the code?

Comment: You totally misunderstood the `runtime thing`. It means that `class A` can hold reference of any of it's subclasses which will be determined at runtime. Their maybe other statement like `A a =new C()` after `A a = new B();` and since their can be many statements like this therefore it's said the the version of the method will be determined at runtime i.e. A will be holding reference of `B` and maybe at some other moment it will be holding the reference of `C`.

Comment: Oooh, now I understand! Your answer is awesome. Very comprehensive and clear. Ofcourse compiler can't decide which version of method to use if referred objects types change at runtime.

Comment: And I guess you wanted to say "statements like `a = new C();` after `A a = new B();`" because `A a = new C();` after `A a = new B();` would cause already used variable name error.

Comment: Yes of course I meant that only.. I may post it as the answer if it completely answers your question so that the question doesn't seems unanswered.. Tell me if you want me to add up something.

Comment: Yes you can post it as an answer because it explains everything I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You totally misunderstood the **run-time** thing.

It means that `class A` can hold reference of any of it's subclasses which will be determined at runtime. Their maybe other statement like `a =new C();` after `A a = new B();` and since their can be many statements like this therefore it's said the the version of the method will be determined at run-time

i.e. `a` will be holding reference of `B` and maybe at some other moment it will be holding the reference of `C` where both `B` and `C` are sub classes of `A`

Here's an example:

```
 class A {

void override()
{
    System.out.println("Inside A");
}

}

 class B extends A
{
     void override()
     {
        System.out.println("Inside B");
     }  

}

 class C extends A
 {
     void override()
     {
         System.out.println("Inside C");
     }
 }

 class Main
 {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
         A a =new A();

         a.override();
         a=new B();

         a.override();

         a=new C();

         a.override();
     }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Inside A
Inside B
Inside C
```

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: It's the variable `a` that can hold a reference of any of the subclasses of `class A`. Also, an example in which the compiler cannot tell the referenced object type would be useful and easy.

Comment: yeah sure! I will add an example! and yeah I corrected the "It's the variable a that can h....." Thanks for pointing!

Comment: I agree with @Andy Thomas, a specific example would make your answer like twice more valuable!

Comment: You could also mark the parts that causes the compiler's confusion to occur with comments. I mean `a = new B();` and `a = new C();` ;]

Comment: In that example, the type of `a` is still known at compile time. It would be useful to show an example in which it cannot be known at compile time, to address the original question *why can't the compiler determine which version (superclass or some subclass) of the method to call?*

Comment: The type of `a` is known but the type of object being referenced to is not. That's the reason the DMD is made for. Am I not right?

Comment: @Salivan - You're right that the type of the local variable `a` is known at compile time. But in this example the class of the object it references at any point is also known at compile time, just as it was in your question. One example of a case where the type is *not* known at compile time is provided by Michael's answer. Another example would be when a method accepts an `A` as a formal parameter.

Comment: @Andy Thomas cool! Thanks for this explanation. It helped me to imagine the situation when compiler can't decide which method to call much more precisely.

Answer (score 4):

A more clear example might be:

```
A a = null;

if (getUserInput() == 'B')
{
  a = new B();
}
else
{
  a = new C();
}

a.overridenMethod();
```

The compiler can't *possibly* know which method here is going to be called - its determined at runtime by the user!

Comment: That's a great answer too, but @Nivedita's one is more general/common. However, accurate and concrete examples are always a great way to understanding! Thanks!